# iTunes: How do you manage your Singles?

Tags: itunes, mp3, music-management

I am having a tough time getting some kind of organization to happen with my singles in itunes.

I enjoy electronic music and ultimately have a tons of songs that have been released as singles and thus have no album.  If there are DJs out there -- how do you guys organize this?!

Itunes seems to love albums but if the song is a single it gets the ugly "Unknown Album" label.  I've considered simply tagging the single tracks' album attribute with "Single" but sometimes a track can belong to an album and be considered a single.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just give the album the same name as the single? Back in the days of actual physical record/tape/CD singles this is how it was done.

Answer (score 1):

Create a play list called singles - playlists are the too you can use in your case of a single that is an album - otherwise I would create an album called singles.

Answer (score 0):

Running iTunes 11.4, I use a Smart Playlist with the parameter `Comments contains Singles`.

- A regular playlist does not live update
- This also permits the other fields (e.g. "Album", et. al.) to be manipulated independently of the singles grouping (which is really a meta piece of information about the album that may or may not apply to the album name itself).

As an aside, this approach allows a song to have multiple parameters to delineate its grouping. For instance, if I have Comments: `Singles Foo`, and Smart Playlists: `Comments contains Singles` & `Comments contains Foo`, then I can have the same song in two different places without having to do any clicking and dragging.